# Maximum and minimum gradient size in CSS

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients, gradient

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #EAEAEA);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #EAEAEA);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #EAEAEA);
background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #EAEAEA);
```

What I basically want to do, is to have some sort of minimum and  maximum gradient length (for instance, the gradient can't be smaller than 500px, even if the background is, and neither can it be bigger than 500px, even if the background is). I have tried using this method:

```
background-size:500px;
```

(aswell as combining it with `background-repeat:y-repeat`), but that doesn't work, since the gradient later on repeats itself from top (and what I would like is for it to maintain its ending-color through the rest of the element).

So shortly, I'm wondering if there's a way to stop a gradient after a certain height, only allowing it to cover a part of the element (hence, preventing it from looking different on all pages, with different sized elements), without using images as background. However, I'd also like to know if using this method is worth it, both when it comes to compatibility and effort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add color stops to your gradient, like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KbncY/3/)**

```css
body, html {
    height:200%;
}
body {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, red 0px, white 500px, white 100%) no-repeat;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, red 0px, white 500px, white 100%) no-repeat;
}
```

[MDN Documentation for Linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this before (I forgot). Better late than never :D

Answer (score 0):

So I made the following test fiddle, and it seems that if you specify a `background-size` then the gradient will be resized to that size regardless of the element dimensions (note that you have to explicitly define a width and a hight for `background-size` to work properly in Firefox).

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/y4b3Z/

I have checked this in latest Chrome, Safari and Firefox and looks the same in all three borwsers.